# Reset status of Azure service bus topic so that it can be consumed by function again

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a azure function with service bus topic trigger, My azure functions calls an API to update the message received from service bus. I am trying setup a retry mechanism when function execution fails. I am wondering if there is way to manipulate the status of service bus topic so that it can be used again to trigger the function.

Comment: A function is triggered by messages found in a subscription or queue, not trigger.

Comment: @SeanFeldman Yes you are right, and thats what is happening right now, what I am trying to do is - after the function is triggered by a subscription, if the execution of function is failed for some reason, I want that subscribed topic to be reset for resubscription, is there a way to do so?

Comment: If the Function execution fails, the message will be sent back to the subscription automatically for re-processing. This continues to happen until the message is dead-lettered. There's nothing special you would need to do.